# Nexmo Handling Errors in Laravel

Tags: laravel, vonage

How I can handle nexmo errors, I use try{}catch(){} but it not work, and I got this error **Nexmo \ Client \ Exception \ Request (29)
Non White-listed Destination - rejected** i know this error but i need  handle it.

this is a code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\NexmoMessage;
//use App\admin\Course;

class ConfirmedCourse extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;
    protected $course;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($course)
    {
     $this->course = $course;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['nexmo'];
    }

 public function toNexmo($notifiable)
    {
      try {
     $message = new NexmoMessage(); 
     $message->content($this->course)
         ->unicode();
     return $message;
    }catch (\Exception $e) {
    $e->getMessage();
    }
 }  
}
```

Comment: try this `try {} catch (\Exception $e) { $e->getMessage()}`

Comment: I just fixed notifications gracefully error handling today. WHere are you calling the notification from? May I see that line of code please

Comment: The call with `$yourModel->notify(....`

Comment: I edit my post, still have error, yes it is for notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this in the past by wrapping the call to `notify()` in the try catch:

```
try {
    $variableToCatch = $YourModel->notify(new ConfirmedCourse($data));
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // Do what you want here... 
    // Log::error('nexmo failed...');
    // echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    // Log::error($e->getMessage());
    // dd($e->getMessage())
}
```

If you post the line where you are calling `notify()` I can update to your use exact needed statement.

Remove the try catch from `ConfirmedCourse` class and put it around the call in the method calling it.

Here is how I handled a slack notification failure:

```
try {
    $slackNotification = $user->notify(new SlackNotification($slackData));
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    Log::error('slack notification failed.');
}
```

Comment: Nice thank u very much :) , i have a question also how get error details from $e?

Comment: That would be `$e->getMessage()`

Comment: Oh, YEs Thank u again :) :)

Comment: No problem, glad I can help. If that fixed it go ahead and mark it as the correct answer  :) Have a great day!